# Sentence construction Do vs does

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

Could someone please let me know if **do** POC (proof of concept) is correct or should I use **does** in the below sentence? Does sound correct to me but according to language rules, should use a singular verb.

> Put extra effort to search for the best sources of information, and **do** POC before making a critical decision.

Comment: If you think *do* should be conjugated, what is the subject for the verb?  What do you think the grammatical role of *put* is in this sentence?

Comment: "Does" is the 3rd person singular but the subject implied the imperative sentence is "you", and that takes "do".

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would use "do POC" because you are being told to do something as an action.

I / you / they "do"

He / she / it "does"

[This](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/vs/using-do-vs-does-properly-in-questions-and-sentences.html) will go over it in more detail!